# Let $(u_n)_n\in\mathbb{R}$, where $u_{n+1}=\frac{1}{3} u_n +2\ \forall n$ and $u_0 \neq 3$. If $(u_n+a)_n$ is a geometric sequence, find $a$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $(u_n)_n\in\mathbb{R}$, where $u_{n+1}=\frac{1}{3} u_n +2\ \forall n$ and $u_0 \neq 3$. If $(u_n+a)_n$ is a geometric sequence, find $a$.

What I had hoped to work here is the property of a geometric sequence that $\alpha_n^2=\alpha_{n-1}\cdot \alpha_{n+1}$, but that led me to a quadratic equation with unknowns $u_0$ and $a$ which, as far as I can see, cannot be solved. The exercise also asks to calculate the limit of the initial sequence, that is easy enough, $L=3$. Could this be related to the geometric sequence in any way? Any clues are much appreciated!

Comment: 1/ Do you know how to calculate $u_{n+1}$ as an explicit formula, say using recurrence relations? (I'm guessing maybe not.)   $\quad$ 2/ If we set $x_n = u_n + a$, then what is the formula for $x_n$?  What would make $x_n$ a geometric sequence?

Comment: Ah, this makes a lot of sense now. Really wondering how finding the general formula for $u_n$ didn't cross my mind! It turns out $a=-3$ is the solution. Thank you very much!